# Can I use KKT to analytically solve this min-max problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am new to optimization and I to solve the following optimization problem:

$$ \min_{g_i(x) \leq 0, h_i(x) = 0} \max_{ \{p_1, \dots,p_n \} \in \Delta} \sum p_i - p_i x_i $$

where the constraints induce convex sets. I thought about writing this equivalently to

$$ \min y $$
$$ y \leq 1 - x_i$$
$$ g_i(x) \leq 0 $$
$$ h_i(x) = 0 $$

and use KKT to solve this. But I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any tips?